# Chart.js only last point

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to show only the last point. Can somebody help with this?

Expected

[image: Expected]

Actual

[image: Actual]

Comment: Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: Provide an example.

Comment: Just in case someone is still wondering how to achieve that (I was!) in a cleaner way than creating an array / overriding class, you can actually pass a function to "pointRadius". More explanation about scriptable property here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#scriptable-options

Here's an example:
> `pointRadius: function(context) { 
    if (context.dataIndex == context.dataset.data.length-1) {
      return 5; // the border radius you want for your lastpoint
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
}`

Comment: @Eve-Amandine this should be the upvoted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I just saw Edi's answer as I submitted mine and he mentioned the `pointRadius`. I noticed this too messing around and as he stated, you can pass in an array to simplify this.

I wrote a method below to "grow" the array (scaling with the data) in order to ensure that the last data point has a radius > 0.

The custom Line chart appears to render much smoother because the native draw function has been modified.

---

> Chart.js 2.0 introduces the concept of controllers for each dataset. Like scales, new controllers can be written as needed.

I copied the source for [`controller.line.js`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/controllers/controller.line.js) and modified the loop for the `draw()` method to only draw the last point. This is the easiest solution without having to figure out how to set an array of radius values.

```
/** Initialize array with radius of n and queue values ahead of it */
function pointRadiusLast(radius, length, initialArray) {
  var result = initialArray || [ radius ];
  while (result.length < length) result.unshift(0); // Place zeros in front
  return result;
}
```

```js
// https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html
var valueOrDefault = Chart.helpers.valueOrDefault;
const lineEnabled = (dataset, options) => valueOrDefault(dataset.showLine, options.showLines)
Chart.defaults.derivedLine = Chart.defaults.line;
var customController = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  /** If you want to EXTEND the draw function.
  draw: function(ease) {
    Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease); // Override the super method
    var meta = this.getMeta();
    var pt0 = meta.data[0];
    var radius = pt0._view.radius;
    var ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
    ctx.save();
    // Custom drawing...
    ctx.restore();
  }
  
  If you want to OVERRIDE the draw function...
  */
  draw: function(ease) {
    var me = this;
    var chart = me.chart;
    var meta = me.getMeta();
    var points = meta.data || [];
    var area = chart.chartArea;
    var ilen = points.length;
    var halfBorderWidth;
    var i = 0;
    if (lineEnabled(me.getDataset(), chart.options)) {
      halfBorderWidth = (meta.dataset._model.borderWidth || 0) / 2;
      Chart.helpers.canvas.clipArea(chart.ctx, {
        left: area.left,
        right: area.right,
        top: area.top - halfBorderWidth,
        bottom: area.bottom + halfBorderWidth
      });
      meta.dataset.draw();
      Chart.helpers.canvas.unclipArea(chart.ctx);
    }
    // Draw the points
    for (; i < ilen; ++i) {
      if (i === ilen - 1) { // Only the last or simply... points[ilen - 1].draw(area)
        points[i].draw(area);
      }
    }
  }
});
Chart.controllers.derivedLine = customController; // Specify type on chart below

var data = [
  { month : 'January'  , low : 25, high : 43 },
  { month : 'February' , low : 27, high : 47 },
  { month : 'March'    , low : 35, high : 56 },
  { month : 'April'    , low : 44, high : 67 },
  { month : 'May'      , low : 54, high : 76 },
  { month : 'June'     , low : 63, high : 85 }
];

var additionalData = [
  { month : 'July'      , low : 68, high : 89 },
  { month : 'August'    , low : 66, high : 87 },
  { month : 'September' , low : 59, high : 81 },
  { month : 'October'   , low : 46, high : 69 },
  { month : 'November'  , low : 37, high : 59 },
  { month : 'December'  , low : 30, high : 48 }
];

var defaults = {
  fill: false,
  lineTension: 0.1,
  borderCapStyle: 'butt',
  borderDash: [],
  borderDashOffset: 0.0,
  borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
  pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
  pointBorderWidth: 1,
  pointHoverRadius: 5,
  pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
  //pointRadius: 0, <-- Do not specify this, we will supply it below
  pointHitRadius: 10
};

/** Initialize array with radius of n and queue values ahead of it */
function pointRadiusLast(radius, length, initialArray) {
  var result = initialArray || [ radius ];
  while (result.length < length) result.unshift(0);
  return result;
}

var dataSets = [
  Object.assign({
    label: "Low",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
    borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: data.map(item => item.low)
  }, defaults),
  Object.assign({
    label: "High",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(192,75,75,0.4)",
    borderColor: "rgba(192,75,75,1)",
    pointBorderColor: "rgba(192,75,75,1)",
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(192,75,75,1)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(192,75,75,1)",
    data: data.map(item => item.high)
  }, defaults)
];

var chartOptions = {
  title : {
    text : 'Weather Averages for Washington, DC',
    display : true
  },
  showLines: true
};

var defaultChart = Chart.Line(document.getElementById('default-line-chart'), {
  data: {
    labels: data.map(item => item.month),
    datasets: dataSets.map(dataset => $.extend(true, {}, dataset, {
      pointRadius : pointRadiusLast(5, data.length)
    }))
  },
  options : $.extend(true, {}, chartOptions, {
    title : {
      text : chartOptions.title.text + ' (Default)'
    }
  })
});

var customChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('custom-line-chart'), {
  type: 'derivedLine',
  data: {
    labels: data.map(item => item.month),
    datasets: dataSets.map(dataset => $.extend(true, {}, dataset, {
      pointRadius : 5
    }))
  },
  options : $.extend(true, {}, chartOptions, {
    title : {
      text : chartOptions.title.text + ' (Custom)'
    }
  })
});

setTimeout(function() {
  var category = 'month', fields = [ 'low', 'high' ];
  var counter = additionalData.length;
  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (counter --> 0) {
      var record = additionalData[additionalData.length - counter - 1];
      addData(defaultChart, record, category, fields);
      addData(customChart, record, category, fields);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 1000); // Update every second
}, 1000); // 1 second delay

function addData(chart, data, xField, yFields) {
  chart.data.labels.push(data[xField]);
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
    dataset.data.push(data[yFields[i]]);
    if (chart.config.type === 'line') { // Only the normal Line chart
      dataset.pointRadius = pointRadiusLast(5, dataset.data.length);
    }
  });
  chart.update();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="default-line-chart" width="400" height="120"></canvas>
<canvas id="custom-line-chart" width="400" height="120"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set the [pointRadius](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties) to zero, eg:

```
var myChart = new Chart(
    ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [...]
            datasets: [
              {
                data: [...],
                pointRadius: 0,  # <<< Here.
              }
            ]
        },
        options: {}
    })
```

For many points (like your question) change pointRadius to array:

```
pointRadius: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
```

Follow my full example in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edicarlos10/omsfcLwv/7/)

Comment: Nice hack. I added a strategy to override the drawing function for a custom Line chart. It renders much smoother.

Comment: ...and simple! oh buddy sounds good nice job! I wanted to show something very simple.